# How to Dynamically load component within a dynamically loaded list component

Tags: angular, angular5, dynamic-loading, viewchild

I have a component which I have loaded dynamically using the view child and the component factory with the code below

```
@Input() dynamicComponent: Observable<any>;
@ViewChild('expandablerow', { read: ViewContainerRef }) rowContainers;
    loadComponent( component) {
        if (component) {
          if (this.rowContainers > 0) { this.rowContainers.clear(); }
          const factory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
          const inlineComponent = this.rowContainers.createComponent(factory);
        }
      }
```

But what I am try to achieve here is to replace one of the list below 
with a details component when the user click on yellow edit button.
I have a function to get the data based on the row clicked but I am stuck there
[image]

Comment: Thanks I was able to figure out a solution

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need dynamic loading? If I were you I would add single `<app-details></app-details>` component and show it instead of list item. You can use css `order` property to put details in the right place in the list and a filter pipe to exclude list item itself from the list.

Or, even more simpler, just make list items consist of two components:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list">
    <div ngIf="item != clicked"></div>
    <div ngIf="item == clicked"></div>
</div>
```

This shouldn't affect performance because when ngIf==true components actually don't exist.

Comment: Thanks but the use case here requires me to use dynamic loading. I was able come up with a solution.